# What is the meaning of the word "mirada"?

Tags: traducción

I'm translating [this song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pRrjt4htXlE) to English. The lyrics include the following line:

> Cómo olvidar tu mirada

It seems to me that "mirada" is a word that is hard to translate to English, making it accurate.

"Look", "glance", or "gaze" simply don't feel right. "Gaze" doesn't seem to have the same "romantic" power I'd say, and doesn't look/sound good. For lack of a better translation, I'd translate the line to

> How could I forget your eyes

But I'm interested to know what do you think would be the translation here and how would you explain the word "mirada" in English.

Comment: I'd go for "your eyes" as suggested or "the look in your eyes".

Answer (score 3):

You can't translate the word because it isn't the same in English, but I would say

> How could I forget the look in your eyes.

I think it sounds more similar to the sentence in Spanish

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, I don't understand why you tend to discard the words that I think that are fittest.
**Gaze** seems a good choice to me.

According to the D.R.A.E

[**mirada**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=PM4mGrz)

> 1. f. Acción y efecto de mirar. [**Action** related to the verb **to look at**]
> 2. f. Vistazo, ojeada.
> 3. f. Modo de mirar, expresión de los ojos. [**How you look at** something or **someone**]

There's nothing explicitly romantic in the definition.

According to [vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/gaze)

> When someone lays eyes on you and keeps looking, it is a **gaze** or a stare

> Gaze is both a verb and a noun. When people daydream, they often gaze
> off into the distance without focusing on anything. Another type of
> gaze, though, is to look very intently at something, as when you gaze
> at the sky making pictures out of clouds

And according to the Cambridge Dictionary

**[gaze](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/gaze)** [verb]

> **to look at** something or **someone** for a long time, especially in surprise or **admiration**, or because you are thinking about something else.

As I understand it, **gaze** as noun represents the action of the verb to gaze.

So

> Cómo olvidar tu **mirada**

is usually understood in a poetic or romantic sense as

> Cómo olvidar cómo me mirabas intensamente con los ojos llenos de amor

Which we can translate to English as

> How could I forget your **gaze**

meaning

> How could I forget how you gaze at me so intensily and full of love

Notice that both suggested explanations, in Spanish and in English, **are not explicitly** set in the original sentence. The author leaves to the audience freedom to imagine what he really meant just with **tu mirada / your gaze**, because it can also mean in both languages that the speaker liked how the eyes of her loved one looked when she was daydreaming.

**Your eyes** or **the look in your eyes** does not reflect the original phrase [explicit] but your interpretation [implicit]. It's not a translation, it's an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Mirada is "the way someone looks at something/someone". It's like saying "I miss the look in your eyes". At least in Argentina.